# AngularJS show loading message before the model load

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, modal-dialog

I am using the Angularjs bootstrap ui-modal pop up in my project. My TemplateUrl is the external link which takes time to give response and which is dynamic and changes often.
So till the time my content from template url shows my model does get show . 
Any idea how can I show the loading message till all my content load from external URL.

I have a link on click of which the following function is called :

```
$scope.viewPopUp = function (id) {
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                  templateUrl: 'myurl'+id,
                  controller: ModalInstanceCtrlQr,
                  opened: function () {
                    console.log('model is opened ')
                    },
                });
                modalInstance.result.then(function (data) {}, function () {
                });
        }
```

Comment: could put modal template in `$templateCache` to avoid making request

Comment: @charlietfl : I have edited my question .. the content of template url is dynamic. So how does the $templateCache would work ?

Comment: please show some code. My approach would be have modal open and show loading icon in the modal while content is being delivered

Comment: @charlietfl : i have added the model open code  ! thanks for your reply !!

Comment: ok so can't you use static templateUrl and load content into modal? Instead of dynamic modal templateURL

Comment: @charlietfl : Agreed .. can u please guide or add a plunker to add dynamic content in static modal template ..again thanks for reply!